# TableView javaFx stock market

Tags: tableview, javafx, reload

I have one small problem with TableView I likend it my ObservableList and i can retrieve the results and put those into my tableview. However :

- I call to my ObservableList each second
- when i get the new result, I delete all the items in my table view and I add the new items

That works but ... each second if for example i select one row in my tableview the preselected column disappear after the table view is refresh... and I feel that is too haeavy. There are other solution ?

the part of my code that Is loading the info for each second is this one :

```
    getColumns().addAll(symbol, bid, ask, high, low, created_at);


    try {
        setItems(getObservableList());

        Timeline fiveSecondsWonder = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                try {
                    setItems(getObservableList());
                } catch (IOException e) {                       
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));

        fiveSecondsWonder.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        fiveSecondsWonder.play();
    } catch (ParseException | IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first clean the items.

```
getItems().clear();
```

and second insert again.

```
setItems(getObservableList());
```